# Reduce the data points on a graph?

Tags: algorithm

I have a huge graph, thousands of data points.

Plotting the graph as is will create a mess with too many lines.

**Question**: what's the best way to reduce the data points?

Example: say my graph is 1000 data points and I need to bring this to 100.

I tried:

a) take 10 of the data points and create a data point based on the average of those. This method produced terrible results and the graph seemed like something else.

b) take the 1st of the 10 data points. This was better than a, but still the graph was different.

Comment: Isn't producing a different graph (one with 100 data points instead of a thousand) is exactly what you're trying to do? Perhaps the problem is *how* it's different?

Comment: It's inaccurate, not just smooth.

Answer (score 7):

There is [Douglas-Peucker algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm) to simplify curves, removing some points, while preserving overall form of curve.
(Note that the remaining points will be distributed slightly unevenly)